# File structure question about ROS

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing a turtlebot arm onto my turtlebot and one of the instructions in the tutorial is :

Setting up the URDF

Next, we have to set up the TurtleBot's hardware description file (URDF) to include the arm. This is done through the TurtleBot bringup script in /etc/ros/turtlebot.

On the TurtleBot, edit /etc/ros/turtlebot/bringup.launch in your favorite text editor and change it to resemble this:

```
<launch>
  <param name="turtlebot_node/gyro_scale_correction" value="1.0"/>
  <param name="turtlebot_node/odom_angular_scale_correction" value="1.0"/>

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/minimal.launch">
    <arg name="urdf_file" value="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_arm_description)/urdf/arm.urdf.xacro'" />
  </include>

</launch>
```

The line

```
<arg name="urdf_file" value="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_arm_description)/urdf/arm.urdf.xacro'" />
```

tells the TurtleBot to use the urdf that includes the arm from the turtlebot_arm_description package.

However, my /etc directory does not contain a ros folder.  There is a ros folder within my /opt file that has a subdirectory electric/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup which contains the following files and folders:

Files:
app_manager.launch
CMakeLists.txt
kinect.launch
Makefile
minimal.launch
ROS_NOBUILD
mainpage.dox
manifest.xml

Folders:
upstart
bin
config
mock_apps
scripts

Does anyone have an idea which file I should be modifying?  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11947/file-structure-question-about-ros/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is new in electric.

```
roscd turtlebot_bringup/upstart 
sudo ./install.bash <<wireless-id>>
```

This will create the etc/ros/electric directory and put turtlebot.launch in the directory. Then you can edit the turtlebot.launch file. This is the file that is launched by sudo service turtlebot start.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-11-16**:
Thank you very much!  I guess this answers my question that the turtlebot_arm urdf file must contain the original turtlebot specs, not just the arm.  Have a great day!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-16**:
change the urdf line in the launch file to have the turtlebot arm instead of just turtlebot..

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-11-16**:
In this case do I just copy that chunk of code over directly, or should I be adding a line from it to the existing file?  More specifically, does the URDF File for the arm contain the rest of the turtlebot as well, or at least link to something that does, or will this change it to just see the arm?

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2011-11-16**:
Thank you very much!